# Python Oracle_cx How to check what is being inserted

Tags: python, oracle, insert

```
sql_insert=""" Insert into DIRECTOR (name,secondName) values (:1,:2) """   
name='Tom' 
second_name='Musk' 
data=[name,second_name] 
try:
     cur.execute(sql_insert,data)   
except Exception as err:
     print('Error DIRECTOR',err) 
else:
     conn.commit()
```

I want to print what is inserted into my database. Like in this case I want to see:

```
Insert into DIRECTOR (name,secondName) values ('Tom','Musk')
```

I tried to print it like this `print(cur.fetchall())` and any different methods but no one is working.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data, look at cx_Oracle [examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/) and [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#sql-queries).

You need to execute a SELECT statement.  You can use various methods including:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
for row in cur.execute("select * from DIRECTOR"):
    print(row)
```

To do tracing of statements you can do your own printing before execution. Or read the [cx_Oracle documentation on Tracing SQL and PL/SQL Statements](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html) which shows how to subclass the `execute()` call so it always prints what is being executed.

Comment: But i want to see all insert statement, not what is inside, like:
Insert into DIRECTOR (name,secondName) values ('Tom','Musk')

Comment: I added a link on tracing to my example.